# Nodejs - AWS SNS publish is called, but message is not being sent

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to publish a SNS message to a single user.
The message is working when I manually press the "Publish Endpoint" button in the AWS console, but I'm trying to send it programmatically using the SNS nodejs SDK.

I have made sure to create a single IAM role giving full access permissions to SNS.

I have made sure to configure it:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});
```

I first create a platform endpoint using `sns.createPlatformEndpoint(endPointParams)` and it works fine so my IAM role is not an issue.

Using the result from that call, I use the `data` to create `publishParams` to make a call right after creating the endpoint:

```
let payload = {
        user : "Hihih test",
        shopping_list : "shopping_item"
    };

    let endPointParams = {
        PlatformApplicationArn: process.env.REACT_APP_SNS_ARN,
        Token: req.body.device_token
    }

const createEndPoint = sns.createPlatformEndpoint(endPointParams).promise();
    createEndPoint.then(data => {

        console.log(data.EndpointArn);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
        
        let publishParams = {
            Message: JSON.stringify(payload),
            MessageStructure: 'json',
            TargetArn: data.EndpointArn
        };

        sns.publish(publishParams, (err, result1) =>{
            console.log("Success");
        });

        return;
    }).then(result => {
        
        res.status(200).send("Success sending invite to user.");

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("Something went wrong sending the invite.");
    });
});
```

The `console.log("Success");` inside `sns.publish()` is being fired, but on the client side, the app does not receive a message. I have also tried multiple times to manually call "Publish Message" in the console and it works fine.

So what could my issue be? I think it's something wrong with my code.

Comment: Have you reviewed your CloudWatch metrics for SNS to identify "NumberOfNotificationsFailed"?

Comment: Bear in mind you're printing "Success" without actually checking whether `err` is set, so that's probably something to check first.

Comment: @404 To be honest I thought the ```.catch``` would have caught the error (my mistake hah). After adding another ```err``` check in ```.publish``` it gave me the error that I needed to structure my payload with a "GCM" or "default" key. That fixed my issue. Thanks haha

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I probably have CloudWatch metrics for SNS configured wrong because it's just staying at 1 for published messages with 0 in the NotificationsFailed. I've checked all the available boxes (5) and set the duration to 3h, but I dont know why any of the fields aren't incrementing even when I manually publish a message. https://i.imgur.com/ywjEDEa.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SNS with GCM you need to structure your JSON payload with the keys `GCM` and `default` or it will throw an err.

```
var payload = {
    default: 'Hello World',
    GCM: {
        notification: {
            title: 'Hello World',
            body: 'Notification Body'
            // other configs can be put here
        }
    }
  };
```